# get agent content and convert it to JSON

Tags: clojure

I'm still newbie in clojure and I'm trying to build application which read two files and write the diffrence on JSON file

```
(defn read-csv
  "reads data."
 []
(with-open [rdr ( 
                   io/reader  "resources/staples_data.csv")]
  (doseq [line (rest(line-seq rdr))]
   (println(vec(re-seq #"[^,]+" line))))))

(defn read-psv
  "reads data."
 []
(with-open [rdr ( 
                   io/reader  "resources/external_data.psv")]
  (doseq [line (rest(line-seq rdr))]
  ; (print(vec(re-seq #"[^|]+" line))))))
(doall(vec(re-seq #"[^|]+" line))))))


(defn process-content []
  (let [csv-records (agent read-csv)
        psv-records (agent read-psv)]
      (json/write-str {"my-data" @csv-records "other-data" @psv-records}))
  )
```

Im getting an exception: Exception Don't know how to write JSON of class $read_csv  clojure.data.json/write-generic (json.clj:385)

Please some help with some explanation, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving the agent a function as its initial value. Perhaps you meant to do an asynchronous call to that function instead? In that case, a `future` is a better match for your scenario as shown. `agent` is synchronous, it's `send` and `send-off` that are async, and they assume you are propagating some state across calls which doesn't match your usage here.

```
(defn process-content []
  (let [csv-records (future-call read-csv)
        psv-records (future-call read-psv)]
      (json/write-str {"my-data" @csv-records "other-data" @psv-records})))
```

The problem after that is that `doseq` is only for side effects, and always returns nil. If you want the results read from the csv files (evaluating eagerly so you are still in the scope of the `with-open` call), use `(doall (for ...))` as a replacement for `(doseq ...)`. Also, the `println` in `read-csv` will need to be removed, or replaced with `(doto (vec (re-seq #"[^,]+" line)) println)` because println always returns nil, and I assume you want the actual data from the file, not a list of nils.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it works but now I'm getting null for both "{\"my-data\":null,\"other-data\":null}"